# Recommendations on how to synchronize Photoshop actions, swatches, etc. across computers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, workflow, actions, shortcuts

Is there any convenient way to synchronize Photoshop settings like *keyboard shortcuts, actions, swatches, custom layer sytles, etc..* across several computers, preferably in an automated way?

So far, I have occasionally synchronized some of the above mentioned by dumping them to my cloud service of choice, but this is a bit too cumbersome and again and again requires figuring out what folders goes what, especially as I am synchronizing between different operating systems.

**Any suggestions on how to automate this, so I would have the same settings on all my machines, no matter where I change them?** Advice for other programs like Illustrator, InDesign, Flash, etc.. is welcome, too.

Comment: Dropbox should be OS independent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hazel for Mac could automate a lot of the copying for you, which could be used in conjunction with Dropbox. Like all things that sync, there might be some situations where you'd want to merge or have some other logic happening, but it might not be possible with that setup — I think the best it could do is blindly copy based on date modified.

http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php

https://www.dropbox.com

I haven't done that myself. It may cause issues, especially if Photoshop etc are open at the time (Hazel can probably account for this though, and only sync when they're closed).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning hazel. I'm afraid I have different operating systems in use, so I need to find a similar tool for Win also and see how they play together.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://alternativeto.net/software/belvedere/) or [this](http://alternativeto.net/software/hygeia/) app could be an alternative to Hazel?

Answer (score 1):

What about something a little more home-brewed:

1. Dropbox (or any cloud service) to keep the files at the ready
2. An [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) script set up on all your workstations

As you might imagine, there's [plenty of rsync info](https://superuser.com/search?q=rsync) over on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of Adobe's apps support aliasing. With InDesign, for instance, I linked a remote directory to the local scripts panel location.

Unfortunately, many of the settings do not allow for aliasing. In those cases you have to write a script to do the synchronization for you. You can use your cloud service to house the files and the script would do the copying for you.

I feel like I'm saying this a lot late but ... hopefully someone with CS6 can give us very good news on this front.